# Laptop battery voltage compatibility

Tags: laptop, battery, compatibility, asus-laptop

I have an **[Asus G501JW](https://www.asus.com/ROG-Republic-Of-Gamers/ROG-G501JW/specifications)** with a battery that swelled. (Noticed that the left-hand side buttons have been slightly displaced.) The stock battery is **15.2V 60Wh 3500mAh** one. The G501JW has different specs and one of those specific laptops has an **11.4V 96Wh 8200mAh**.

Would the bigger capacity battery be compatible with my laptop? I asked Asus about it and they just told me to contact the nearest service center. Asked the service center and they said they **don't know**, they just follow the list of stock parts installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(@tetsujin was correct and I wish he had not deleted his answer)

You can't safely put this battery in your laptop because - assuming the physical configuration allows it - which I suspect won't be the case - when the charger is connected it will put more voltage then the battery can safely handle - with luck there will be protective circuitry to prevent an explosion - but it's not a good idea.